# What's wrong in this proof of $10$ is a solitary number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisor-sum

Friendly numbers are two or more natural numbers with a common abundancy, the ratio between the sum of divisors of a number and the number itself. Two numbers with the same abundancy form a friendly pair.
A number that is not part of any friendly pair is called **[solitary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solitary_number)**. `I have found a very elementary proof of 10 being a solitary number which is an open problem. So I would like to find a mistake in my proof.` Let $\sigma(n)$ be the sum of divisor function.

For $10$ to have a friendly pair we have to find another solution to $$\sigma(5x)=9x$$
 $$6 \ \sigma(x) = 9x \ \text{(Assuming (5,x)=1)}$$
 $$2\ \sigma(x)=3x$$
Now Let $x=2^kp$ where $p \in \mathbb{N}$ ,$(p,z)=1$
$$2(2^{k+1}-1) \sigma(p)=3 \cdot 2^kp$$
$$\frac{\sigma(p)}{p}=\frac{3 \cdot 2^{k-1}}{2^{k+1}-1}$$
Now as any number has atleast two prime factors one and itself hence ,
$$\frac{\sigma(p)}{p}>1$$
$$ \implies3 \cdot 2^{k-1}>2^{k+1}-1$$
Which can be showed impossible for $k>0$.

Now  let us assume that $x$ is in the form $x=5^t2^kq$ 
$$\frac{2(5^{t+1}-1)(2^{k+1}-1) \sigma(q)}{4}=3 \cdot 5^t \cdot 2^k \cdot q$$
$$(5^{t+1}-1)(2^{k+1}-1) \sigma(q)=3 \cdot 5^t \cdot 2^{k+1} \cdot q$$
$$\frac{\sigma(q)}{q}=\frac{3 \cdot 5^t \cdot 2^{k+1} }{(5^{t+1}-1)(2^{k+1}-1)}$$
Which by proceeding as above ie. by the fact $\frac{\sigma(q)}{q}>1$ can be shown not possible.

Thus no friendly pair of $10$ is possible. Thus $10$ is solitary.

Comment: Why solution for $\sigma(5x)=9x$

Comment: Looks like you're considering two cases: one where $(5,x)=1$ and one where $5 \;|\; x$.  In the latter case, you no longer have $2\sigma(x)=3x$, since you derived that equation assuming $(5,x)=1$.

Comment: In addition to what @mjqxxx said, you assume $k>0$, but you need to consider the case $k=0$ as well.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the main problem. First of all, since:

$$\frac{\sigma(10)}{10} = \frac{\sigma(2)\sigma(5)}{10} = \frac{(1+2)(1+5)}{10} = \frac{18}{10} = \frac95$$

a hypothetical friend $x\in\mathbb{N}$ of $10$ must satisfy:

$$\frac{\sigma(x)}{x}=\frac95$$

You search for $2\sigma(x)=3x$ which is wrong. In your very first equation the "5" is inside the $\sigma$ function when it should be outside. Therefore "5" becomes "6" in your proof attempt which is wrong. The irrelevant equation $\frac{\sigma(x)}{x}=\frac32$ is solved by $x=2$ only, by the way. The fact that $2$ is solitary is not new.

Comment: His 5 was purposely made into 6. Given that x and 5 were coprime, the sum of factors of 5x is 6 times the sum if factors of x. 5+1=6.

Comment: @the4seasons Yes, I can see how he comes from $\sigma(5x)=9x$ to the next line $6\sigma(x)=9x$ under his assumption. However, the error is before that. There is no reason to regard $\sigma(5x)=9x$ in the first place. Where does that come from?! Bhaskar Vashishth asked the same in an immediate comment to the question. From my post above it should be clear that we should solve $5\sigma(x)=9x$. So his "5" starts under the parenthesis (in the argument to $\sigma$) for no good reason! After that, it becomes a "6", but that is not the error.

Comment: May i explain. The abundancy of 10 is 9/5. For there to be a number which has the same abundancy, the number also has to be a multiple of 5. This is not cross-multiplication, this is just stating the friendly number as 5x.

Comment: @the4seasons Interesting! So if we call the friendly number candidate $5x$, and if we assume $\gcd(5,x)=1$, then the we are led to and impossible equation. Therefore the asker actually proves that no friend of $10$ can be of the form $5x$ with $\gcd(5,x)=1$. Because if that $x$ existed, it would be a friend of $2$, and $2$ is known to be a solitary number. Agree?

Comment: Yep! and if x=2, 5x=10 and 10 is a friend with itself! (which makes it solitary)

Comment: I stopped reading the OP's proof at the point $\sigma (5x)=9x.$  If $\sigma (y)=9y/5 ,$  how does it follow that $5$ divides $y$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That is OK. If any $y$ satisfy $\sigma(y)/y=9/5$, then you can see the left-hand side as some fraction not in lowest terms. When reducing the fraction which has denominator $y$, we are led to the irreducible fraction $9/5$ with denominator $5$. Therefore the original denominator $y$ has $5$ as a factor. So $y$ is of the form $y=5x$. We then search for $\sigma(5x)/(5x)=9/5 \Leftrightarrow \sigma(5x)/x = 9$. There are two cases. If $\gcd(5,x)=1$, we are led to $x=2$, and the original $y$ is $10$, so no friends there. The other case, $\gcd(5,x)>1$, is harder. Here, $25|y$.

Comment: I feel silly having overlooked that obvious point about $5|y$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem lies in the last part of your proof. The sum of factors of q over q is definitely more than 1. Remember that the sum of factors include q as a factor as well. Therefore, the sum of factors of q over q should be more than 1 and a friend is still possible.

Comment: What middle part of the proof are you referring to? The asker seems to agree that $\frac{\sigma(x)}{x}>1$ for all $x>1$. However, the first error is that the proof starts by considering a wrong equation at the very beginning.

Comment: The asker states that "Which by proceeding as above ie. by the fact σ(q)/q>1 can be shown not possible." on the second last line. He didn't agree, he disagreed there. I do realise that I said the middle while it was the second last line. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the first part is straightforward and correct, even if it is missing some helpful details. This part demonstrates simply that 10 cannot divide its friend(s).

In the second part, your conclusion that the result holds is based on the assumption that $k$ (the exponent for 2) is nonzero. Allowing $k=0$, the RHS of the offending equation becomes $$\frac{6\cdot5^{t}}{5^{t+1}-1}$$ which is definitely greater than 1.

A second error in the second part is in the setup. Specifically, you used the $$2\sigma(x)=3x$$ setup in a way that was unjustified, since it hinged on $(5,x)=1$. The proper setup for the second part would be $$\frac{(2^{k+1}-1)(5^{t+1}-1)\sigma(q)}{4\cdot2^k5^tq}=\frac{9}{5}$$ since this is what happens when $5|x$.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, after seeing that ten has not been proved as a solitary number jumped straight to your proof. However, the error is in the first step where you claim $\sigma(5x) = 6\sigma(x)$. Disproving this is merely a game of examples where it does not work and that is when x is a multiple of $5$. For example, $10$; $\sigma(50) = 93$, while $6\sigma(10) = 108$.

Comment: Note the introduction to using [mathematical expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score -1):

according to my proof 0 is not solitary
a solitary number is a number which does not have any friends.
Solitary Number include all primes, power of prime(i can give you the proof) and number which have g.c.d.(n,Sigma(n))=1

So here n = 10
And Sigma(n=10)=18[can be found easily
so g.c.d.(10,Sigma(10))=2
therefore 10 is not solitary number

in case of any defect you can mail me the defect in the proof
thanks

Comment: This is an old question which already has a well-accepted answer. You have not contributed anything new here.